# Cross Origin Request Only Supported With HTTP with PreloadJS (CreateJS)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, createjs

I am making a game on createJS and I while adding the LoadQueue to load images, I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/me/programming/assets/background.png. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. createjs-2013.12.12.min.js:15
```

I already searched this problem, and I now know this happens because it's supposed to be on a server to work. However, right now I'm just in testing so I want to be able to test this even when offline (and I don't have a server).

I've looked at the proposed solutions to this. I've tried running Google Chrome with

```
--allow-file-access-from-files
```

and

```
--disable-web-security
```

but neither work.

Is there a way to run PreloadJS without actually putting the images on a server? If not, I would think that this would make the CreateJS Suite and even HTML5 as a whole an unattractive tool for making games compared to something that would allow loading of local files. I hope I'm wrong and that's not true.

Comment: Look into running a local server, such as MAMP (mac) or XAMPP (pc). There are lots of other ways, but this is an easy way to set up and go.

Answer (score 0):

As Lanny proposed in a comment, it will probably be easier in the long run to just "bite the bullet" and use a local HTTP server, than to force things in a way that was not intended (like with the Chrome command-line arguments). There are many ways in which a browser behaves differently when working with local URLs (`file://` instead of `http://`), so it is usually better to have a "realistic" environment right from the start.

Guessing from the path in your error message, it looks like you are running Mac OS X, which I think comes with Python 2.7 installed by default, so a very simple way to run a local HTTP server without having to install anything would be calling:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

In a terminal, in the root folder of your CreateJS project.